# Fraction of two prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, fractions

Is there any name or special mathematical importance for fractions of two prime numbers, e.g. 7/11 or 103/277?

Comment: They're trivially irreducible.

Comment: I think that "convenience store numbers" might be a good neologism (based on the 7/11 example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the two primes are the same, in which case the ratio is of course just $1$, their ratio is a fraction that is in its 'simplest form'.